# i have an idea for a biometric app

Tags: biometrics

is it possible to use the touch api as to read in and authenticate fingerprints? i have an idea for a biometric app but i want to make sure the necessary api's are available first.

thanks

Comment: What device? If you are talking about the iPhone, then no: the touchpad hardware is not too precise to recognize minor pressure differences caused by the finger terrain.

Comment: @Pindatjuh: I vote your comment up for the term "finger terrain".

Comment: Check this article out:  http://blogs.zdnet.com/Apple/?p=6352 most touchscreens (of which these are good examples) can barely track your finger as it moves across the screen in a straight line.

Answer (score 6):

No - touch screens and touch pads do not have anywhere near enough resolution for this. You need an optical fingerprint reader.

Answer (score 5):

No, the sensitivity of the touch interface doesn't give you the resolution to see fingerprints.